# what is the different between np.percentile vs 1.96*np.sqrt in datacamp?

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval, stat

I have learnt datacamp on "Statistical Simulation in Python".
I am confused between np.percentile vs 1.96*np.sqrt.
As far as I know, 1.96*np.sqrt. is the way to calculate the confidential interval.
However, why does the course sometimes use np.percentile to calcuate confidential interval?

Some example code from the course.

```
    # Calculate bootstrapped mean and 95% confidence interval.
boot_mean = np.mean(mean_lengths)
boot_95_ci = np.percentile(mean_lengths, [2.5, 97.5])enter code here


# Assuming normality, calculate lower and upper 95% confidence intervals
jk_lower_ci = jk_median_length - 1.96*np.sqrt(jk_var)
jk_upper_ci = jk_median_length + 1.96*np.sqrt(jk_var)
```

Comment: With close to 0 details provided, I'd assume one is an empirical estimate, while the other is theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

np.percentile(mean_lengths, [2.5, 97.5]) is the CI of bootstrap CI process (it is an intervel of the means from bootstrap)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).